# Why is Mockito complaining about the return type of the method call inside the mocked method?

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock the following methods:

```
final public String getDtaValueAsString(String attrib) {
    String v = getDtaValue(attrib);
    if(v != null && !v.equals("")){
        return v;
    }
    return null;
}

final public Long getDtaValueAsLong(String attrib) {
    String v = getDtaValue(attrib);
    if(v != null && !v.equals("")){
        return LongUtil.valueOf(v);
    }
    return null;
}
```

via:

```
when(dta.getDtaValueAsString(DtaData.NAME)).thenReturn(name);
when(dta.getDtaValueAsLong(DtaData.POSITION)).thenReturn(sortNumber);
```

but I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Long cannot be returned by getDtaValue()
getDtaValue() should return String
```

How can I mock that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mock `final` methods (`getDtaValueAsString` and `getDtaValueAsLong`) on your `dta` object.

Remove the `final` modifier from these methods and then they should be mockable.

---

How does it work underneath: Mockito uses a lot of class-generating magic to generate the mocks in `when(...)` calls. Unfortunately, this causes final methods / final classes to be hard/impossible to mock. There are tools like PowerMock that can allow you to do so.

**However**, if the code is under your control, consider extracting an interface for that `dta`, and mocking it instead. That would also be in line with "program to interface not to implementation" paradigm.

Comment: Removing the final modifier did the trick. Interesting that mocking the final method `getDtaValueAsString` did work but not the `getDtaValueAsLong` method.